# How "not to remove 'php' extension from specific page?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-extension

I am newbie in coding and need your help. I have hidden my .php extension via .htaccess with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

But there is one page (submit.php) where .php extension is required to work my code in that page, otherwise it shows a blank page. Is there any way around to whitelist specific page form not to remove .php extension?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your htaccess file ,add the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^submit\.php$ - [L]
```

This will exclude the **/submit.php** URI from your rules.