# Remove php/html extensions and exclude one specific file from the rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

My `.htaccess` rules remove all `.html` and `.php` extensions from URL.

However I need to exclude one specific `.php` file from this rule, for example the file `mailscript/sendmail.php`

How would that be possible on the current rules configuration I have now ?

**.htaccess**

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

I tried to apply `RewriteRule ^sendmail\.php$ [L]` based [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962659/4690886) but it did not work with my current rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this rule to skip `sendmail.php`:

```
RewriteRule (?:^|/)sendmail\.php$ - [L,NC]
```

Add this rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line.